# Runtime class casting java

Tags: java, casting

How to convert source object to target object?

```
public static Object convertObject(Object source, Object target){
      return (target.getClass())source;    // IDE: 'not a statement'
}
```

Comment: and you try to cast `source` to `java.lang.Class` of the target, not to the target's actual class.

Comment: No longer relevant. It still does not work.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Post an answer, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Casting makes no change to the underlying type (except for primitives), so there is nothing to do here. If you want to perform some transformation, just do that. You might find the interface `java.util.function.Function` useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do, but to cast to a runtime type, you need the method [Class.cast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)):

```
public static Object convertObject(Object source, Object target){
      return target.getClass().cast(source);
}
```

This does what you are asking, but it doesn't really make much sense. It does throw `java.lang.ClassCastException` at runtime if the types don't actuelly match. This check is actually pretty much the only thing this does.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do some conversion, this should be done via generic method:

```java
public static <T> T convert(Object source, Class<T> targetClass) {
      return targetClass.cast(source);
}

public static Object convertObject(Object source, Object target) {
      return target.getClass().cast(source);
}
```

At least after calling this method, no explicit casting is required.

```java
static class A {
    String foo() { return "A"; };
}

static class B extends A {
    String foo() { return "B"; };
}

static class C extends B {
    String foo() { return "C"; };
}
```

test

```
A c = new C();
A b1 = new B();

B b = convert(c, B.class);
B b2 = convertObject(c, b1); // incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to B
// explicit casting needed (B) convertObject(c, b1);
```